# Getting unknown property: backend\models\ProductAttribute::Size:Yellow,Length:30

Tags: gridview, yii2

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,   
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],                
         [
            'attribute' =>'id_product_attribute',
            'label' => 'Attribute Value-Pair',
            'value'=>ProductAttributeController::attributepair(),
         ],
        'price',
        'weight',
    ],      
]); ?>

public function attributepair(){     

    $id = $_GET['id'];        
    $attribute_pair = $this->context->actionAttributecombination($id);        
    $attribute_pair = rtrim($attribute_pair, ",");
    return $attribute_pair;
}
```

Where $attribute_pair returns a string "Size:Yellow,Length:30".How can i show this data inside gridview?

Comment: It shows the error "Getting unknown property: backend\models\ProductAttribute::Size:Yellow,Length:30".
How can i fix the issue?

Comment: show your ProductAttribute Model please..

Answer (score 0):

Your function must be `static` as you are using `::`

```
public static function attributepair(){     

    $id = $_GET['id'];        
    $attribute_pair = $this->context->actionAttributecombination($id);        
    $attribute_pair = rtrim($attribute_pair, ",");
    return $attribute_pair;
}
```

Comment: Atlast i fixed the issue.
'value'=>function ($model) {               
                $shoparray=ProductAttributeController::attributepair();                
                return $shoparray;                      
               },